# In ASP.NET MVC3, is there a way to make a [RegularExpression] tag dynamic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have something in my viewmodel like

```
[RegularExpression(...)]
public string PenguinGenome
{
    get;set;
}

public int PenguinSpecies
{ 
    get; set;
}
```

Is there a way to make ... dynamic based on PenguinSpecies?

ie:

```
[RegularExpression(GetExpression(PenguinSpeciesId))]
public string PenguinGenome
{
    get;set;
}

public int PenguinSpeciesId
{ 
    get; set;
}

public string GetExpression(int speciesId)
{
    if (.....)
       return "[some regex]";
}
```

This won't work because PenguinSpeciesId doesn't exist in the context. What's the best workaround?

Comment: The problem is that attributes can't contain any non-static references because they're part of the metadata for a particular class/property/whatever. So you can't call any methods or properties to instantiate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is an article](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/build-model-aware-custom-validation-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc-2/) for ASP.NET MVC2, but the process is pretty close to the same for ASP.NET MVC3.

Basically you will need to create your own custom validator that can look at the object, and then determine the proper way to validate.

Answer (score 0):

RegularExpression validator is not really what you want. You want to validate PenguinGenome based on the value of another model property. In other words - you dont want property validation here, but model validation.

You can use model-aware validation attribute, but i personally wouldnt - because it "hides" dependency (nobody can tell from looking at model class, that PenguinGenome validation depends on PenguinSpeciesId). I would rather use IValidatableObject here.

Comment: With a regular expression tag it will automatically put the regex validation in my view. Will this solution do the same?

Comment: No, unfortunately autogenerated client-side validation wont work in your scenario - the generated regex would have to change with any change of PenguinSpeciesId - that is not supported out of the box. You must eighter use custom validation logic (jquery is your friend) or MVC supported remote validation.